# ClickEvent in message

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to write a `tooltip` which is clickable. Currently i am thinking about a `usercontrol` which derives from `IButtonControl` and `ToolTip`.

```
public partial class JLToolTip : ToolTip, IButtonControl
```

As far as I can see it does everything a normal `tooltip` should do but if I click it
, the window loses shortly the focus until it gets it after a half second or so back.

The first thing i am trying to accomplish is this.

```
public void PerformClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("CLICK");
}
```

I know it looks dead simple but I can't find the proper solution or why it won't work
I hope anybody of you does have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is clickable and composable tooltip control, I recomment [Simple Popup Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control). You can easily extend it and adopt it to your needs.

I don't fully understand your question, but I think this is what you are looking for.